# How to calculate number of days between two dates when one of them is nullable in the database?

Tags: c#, datetime, if-statement

I have two dates: `FromDate` and `ToDate`. Out of the two, `ToDate` is `nullable`. However, I need to calculate the number of days between `ToDate` and `FromDate` for the cases when `ToDate` is not null.

I have the following code:

```
if(ToDate != null)
{
    var days = (ToDate - FromDate).TotalDays();
}
```

However, upon doing so, I get the following error:

> 'TimeSpan? does not contain a definition for `TotalDays` and no extension method `TotalDays` accepting a first argument of type `TimeSpan?` could be found (are you missing a user directive or an assembly reference?'

I understand why I am getting this error. I want to know a way around this so that I can calculate the number of days between `ToDate` and `FromDate`.

Comment: Use `ToDate.Value`

Comment: The comment above and the answer given are correct. However there might be an even more concise way to express this logic; can you say what you are doing if `ToDate` *is* null?

Comment: I was just trying to imply that I wanted to check if the date was not null. I know I don't need to check that. Thank you for the comment.

Comment: Stephen, could you post an answer so that I can mark it as correct. Since you have the correct answer first, you deserve to get the credit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(ToDate.HasValue)
{
    var days = (ToDate.Value - FromDate).TotalDays();
}
```

This code should work. 
Your problem that `TimeSpan?` doesn't have extension method `TotalDays` while `TimeSpan` has it. So you need just to get not nullable value as difference.

[Msdn link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.totaldays?view=netframework-4.7.2)